# Deleting a SubDag from Airflow's database

Tags: airflow

I created 4 SubDags within the main Dag which will run on different schedule_interval. I removed the operation of one SubDag but it still appears on Airflow's Database. Will that entry in the database execute? Is there a way to delete that from Airflow's database?

Answer (score 0):

The record will persist in the database, however if the DAG isn't actually present on the scheduler (and workers depending on your executor), it can't be added to the DagBag and won't be run.

Having a look at this [simplified scheduler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Scheduler+Basics) of what the scheduler does:

```
def _do_dags(self, dagbag, dags, tis_out):
    """
    Iterates over the dags and schedules and processes them
    """
    for dag in dags:
        self.logger.debug("Scheduling {}".format(dag.dag_id))
        dag = dagbag.get_dag(dag.dag_id)
        if not dag:
            continue
        try:
            self.schedule_dag(dag)
            self.process_dag(dag, tis_out)
            self.manage_slas(dag)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.exception(e)
```

The scheduler will check if the dag is contained in the DagBag before it does any processing on it.  Entries for DAGs are kept in the database to maintain the historical record of what dates have been processed should you re-add it in the future. But for all intents and purposes, you can treat a missing DAG as a paused DAG.